# Generating downloadable .CSV file in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, csv

I'm having problems with generating downloadable .CSV files in PHP. In my page (index.php) I have a form that calls itself. On same page I've also included php file (csvHandler.php) that checks if form was submitted and then generates CSV file. This works OK. But the problem is, when I add headers (to auto-download file) it adds whole php code to that CSV file. Any idea how to solve this?

This is a code of csvHandler.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_dCSV'])){
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');    
    header('Expires: 0');
    $message = "";
    $institutions = explode_institutions();
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    foreach ($institutions as $inst){
        fputcsv($fp, $inst);        
    }
    echo "Export successful";
}
```

When I run this code it downloads a CSV file, but there is complete PHP code of index.php. Any idea?

(edited)
index.php:

```
<html>
 <head>title</head>
 <body>
  ...html code 1...

  <form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
   <button type="submit" name="submit_dCSV" value="submit"></button>
  </form>

  <? include "csvHandler.php"; ?>

  ...html code 2...
 </body>
</html>
```

If I put ob_clean() and ob_start() at start of csvHandler.php it generates csv files with correct data, but it adds all the code bellow include (...html code 2..., /body, /html,...). How to fix that?

Comment: ob_clean(); ob_start();

Comment: @Naruto could you write this out in the form of an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is your output buffering...

Because you're already making and outputting HTML code, your buffer has output, if you clean it, and (re)start it, your problem should be solved.

You can just add [ob_clean()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php) and [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) at the beginning of this all:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_dCSV'])){
    ob_clean();
    ob_start();
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');    
    header('Expires: 0');
    $message = "";
    $institutions = explode_institutions();
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    foreach ($institutions as $inst){
        fputcsv($fp, $inst);        
    }
    echo "Export successful";
}
```

Comment: This works great for upper part of code (code before my function). But lower part (code behind my function) is still there. any idea?

Comment: @Naruto- In case of safari this code is not working please help.